# Perl nested loop to print out two arrays n number of times in different patterns

Tags: arrays, perl, loops

I am looking to create a loop where the following data is printed n number of times. So given:"

```
n = 9;
@a = (1, 2 ,3);
@b = (a, b, c);


$a[0] = 1 $b[0] = a
$a[0] = 1 $b[1] = b
$a[1] = 2 $b[2] = c
$a[1] = 2 $b[0] = a
$a[2] = 3 $b[1] = b
$a[2] = 3 $b[2] = c
$a[0] = 1 $b[0] = a
$a[0] = 1 $b[1] = b
$a[1] = 2 $b[2] = c
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just cycling through the indexes.

However, you need to put a lot more effort into both clarifying your question and demonstrating what you've tried thus far.

The following does reproduce your desired output, but it's really impossible to say if it's what you actually need without more information:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $n = 9;
my @a = qw(1 2 3);
my @b = qw(a b c);

for my $i ( 0 .. $n - 1 ) {
    my $a_index = ( $i / 2 ) % 3;
    my $b_index = $i % 3;
    printf "\$a[%d] = %s \$b[%d] = %s\n", $a_index, $a[$a_index], $b_index, $b[$b_index];
}
```

Outputs:

```
$a[0] = 1 $b[0] = a
$a[0] = 1 $b[1] = b
$a[1] = 2 $b[2] = c
$a[1] = 2 $b[0] = a
$a[2] = 3 $b[1] = b
$a[2] = 3 $b[2] = c
$a[0] = 1 $b[0] = a
$a[0] = 1 $b[1] = b
$a[1] = 2 $b[2] = c
```